# Any ebooks on making javascript games with pure DOM not canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

Ok I have been slowly learning html and javascript for 2 months now. I want to start making games , so far I have made a pop quiz app and number guessing game for android using a wrapper (Andromo). I want to start making platformers so I started looking online for tutorials and getting ebooks. The problem with ebooks and online is they always switch to canvas when it gets to the action games part.
  I dont understand why I can't make games using just DOM rather than canvas. The reason I don't like canvas is there are some things that seem like its meant to make you type forever. Most online examples they make a dot on the screen and it takes a ton of code.
EXAMPLE
Javascript DOM to make an image onscreen

```
<img src="powerman.png" width="50 height="50" >
```

Now if you do it on canvas its like this

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var draw   = canvas.getContext("2d");

var monster = new Image();
monster.addEventListener("load",loadHandler,false);
monster.src= "powerman.png";

function loadHandler()
{
draw.drawImage(monster,0,0);
```

That seems like a ton of unnessary coding, I don't understand how canvas is supposed to be faster when it has line after line of coding for every simple thing. And thats just to display an image , when you make a charactor move onscreen forget it on DOM you just put the direction your going in, on canvas you have to clearect() and delete previous image as your moving which is too much .I almost feel as if canvas was made to get people to quit coding.
 I enjoy coding but it has to make sense to me. This is why if you know of any ebooks or tutorials of platform game making in pure DOM that will be so helpful.

Comment: When i was just introduced to JQuery i made a simple JQuery snake and ladder game without any html5 http://funscripts.popbild.com/snakeladder/

Comment: You certainly can use normal DOM elements and there are a lot of libraries that make it significantly easier (and more performant) like Greensock's Tweenlite/Max. Plus, you have the benefit of styling things with CSS this way so you can easily adjust your sprites without delving into complex canvas geometry.

Comment: Hmmm...a game with little or no coding?  Maybe SVG + CSS? Check out Snap.svg and this demo game created with Snap: http://snapsvg.io/demos/#game

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not going to find any books on the topic because using the DOM to create a game is a bad idea. However, it might work for some game that are not that graphic intensive. If you're interested, Google made a game without the canvas a few years ago. You can have a look at it: http://macek.github.io/google_pacman/

Comment: Ok so making a game using pure javascript without canvas is supposed to run slower? The part that I don't understand is that a game made with just javascript will have way less coding than one with canvas. Plus alot of books always cover drawing functions that I wont use because I will have images made. If I sit there drawing programing wise it would take a massive amount of  time coding rather than working on game logic, which is the part I like.

Comment: The amount of code used does not to the complexity or the performance of a program. Just because you have to type more code doesn't mean your program that is it slower. The DOM was designed to manipulate static document elements. It was not designed for game.